# Strange Focus Issues on specific Android Honeycomb tablet (Orange Tahiti)

Tags: android, focus, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a form-based app where each form is a scrollable layout of various types of view (`RadioButton`, `Spinner`, `EditText` views, etc).  I have tested the app on a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4 and an Advent Vega with Android 4 and there are no issues with focus.  I can scroll through the form without any problems.

However, when I test on the target device (a Android 3.2 Orange Tahiti which is a rebranded  Huawei MediaPad), suddenly the focus behaviour is very different. It's difficult to know exactly what the tablet is trying to do. If I hide the soft keyboard and scroll, the tablet tries to focus on EditText views as they come into view and pops up the keyboard every time it successfully focuses which is very annoying.  Also, on occasion the tablet will randomly jump to the last `EditText` in the form, scrolling the user away from their position in the form.

I have tried various focus settings (`requestFocus`, `clearFocus()`, `descendantFocusability`, etc) to no avail.  However, I doubt the problem has anything to do with config as it works fine on other devices.

Is it possible that the focus behaviour in Honeycomb is different to all other versions of Android?  I doubt it but it's worth finding out for sure before resorting to installing a custom ROM just in case I have overlooked a Honeycomb-specific config setting that might fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as this is a problem (or included "feature") of the branded version of Honeycomb that comes with an Orange Tahiti.

Upgrading to ICS will sort it out and scrolling, etc will behave as you would expect. Follow the below link for instructions...

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1544855